# Audit.WebAPI configuration

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, json.net, audit.net

I am using version 7.0.6 of Audit.NET.
I added the following line to my WEB API registration method

```
config.Filters.Add(new Audit.WebApi.AuditApiAttribute());
```

When i run the application it gives the following runtime error

`self referencing loop detected with type Appinstance.Path` `'Action.ActionParameters.request.Properties.MS_HttpContext.ApplicationInstance.Context'.`

I am using latest version of `Newtonsoft.JSON` from Nuget.

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide the stack trace?

That error means Newtonsoft.Json was unable to serialize an object that has a reference loop, but the json conversion used by default on Audit.NET already handles this, by ignoring the reference loops with [ReferenceLoopHandling](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ReferenceLoopHandlingIgnore.htm) setting set to Ignore.

https://github.com/thepirat000/Audit.NET/blob/master/src/Audit.NET/AuditEvent.cs#L73

Are you using a custom data provider to save the events?

If so, please be sure to use the provided AuditEvent [ToJson](https://github.com/thepirat000/Audit.NET/blob/master/src/Audit.NET/AuditEvent.cs#L73) method, or any other method that handles self references.

Comment: Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException occurred
Message: Exception thrown: 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException' in Newtonsoft.Json.dll

Additional information: Self referencing loop detected for property 'ApplicationInstance' with type 'ASP.global_asax'. Path 'Action.ActionParameters.request.Properties.MS_HttpContext.ApplicationInstance.Context'.

Comment: My webapi is running on local system and i have used audit's sqldataprovider to log audit entries.

Comment: Feel free to open a new issue https://github.com/thepirat000/Audit.NET/issues/new so you can provide more details on how to reproduce it.